# Sum of the sequences (It is not easy)

Tags: summation

Prove that $1+4+9+16+...+n^2= \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$,

Answer (score 1):

It can be proved by mathematical induction. 
Let p(k) be  1+4.. +k²=1/6{k(k+1)( 2k+1)}
P(k+1) = 1+4+...+k²+(k+1) ²
             =1/6{k(k+1) (2k+1) } +(k+1) ²
Solving the above equation, we get 
           P(k+1) =1/6{(k+1) (k+2) (2k+3) }
Thus,  the above equation is true for all n (natural numbers).